# Using a previously borrowed Result in Rust

Tags: rust

I'd like to enhance an error message with the contents of a previous `Ok`, if that was the previous `Result`, but I found no obvious way of going about it. To demonstrate the issue, I've written the following functions eulating the key elements of my problem:

```
type SResult<T> = std::result::Result<T, Vec<String>>;

fn main_loop(input: impl BufRead,
            mut output: impl Write,
            mut outerr: impl Write) -> SResult<()> {
    for (index, next_line) in input.lines().enumerate() {
        let processed = process(next_line.map_err(|e| to_vec(e)), index);
        match processed {
            Err(ref error) if error.last().unwrap().starts_with("fatal") =>
                processed.map(|_| ())?,
            Err(ref error) => {
                let mut error = error.to_owned();
                writeln!(outerr, "Error: {}", error.pop().unwrap());
                // Line contents should be printed here
                while !error.is_empty() {
                    writeln!(outerr, "caused by: {}", error.pop().unwrap());
                }
            },
            Ok(ref message) => writeln!(output, "{}", message).map_err(|e| to_vec(e))?
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn process(next_line: SResult<String>, index: usize) -> SResult<String> {
    let result = &mut next_line.and_then(eval);
    match result {
        Err(ref mut error) if error.last().unwrap().starts_with("fatal") =>
            chain(result, format!("fatal error at {}", index + 1)),
        Err(ref mut error) =>
            chain(result, format!("error at {}", index + 1)),
        _ => result.to_owned()
    }
}

fn eval<'a>(line: String) -> SResult<String> {
    match line.as_ref() {
        "first" => Err(vec!["bad line".to_owned()]),
        "second" => Ok("good line".to_owned()),
        _ => Err(vec!["fatal error".to_owned()])
    }
}
```

The functions `to_vec` and `chain` correspond to `.into()` and error-chain's `.chain_err` of my actual problem, to cut down on dependencies:

```
fn to_vec(error: std::io::Error) -> Vec<String> {
    vec![format!("{}", error)]
}

fn chain(result: &mut SResult<String>, message: String) -> SResult<String> {
    match result {
        Ok(_) => result.to_owned(),
        Err(ref mut error) => {
            error.push(message);
            Err(error.to_owned())
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to print the actual line that had an error where you see a comment in the `main_loop` function.  The code above can be tested by this test:

```
#[test]
fn test_case() {
    let data = ["first", "second", "third"].join("\n");
    let input = Cursor::new(data);
    let mut output = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(1024);
    let mut error = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(1024);
    let result = main_loop(input, &mut output, &mut error);
    let output_as_text = std::str::from_utf8(&output).unwrap();
    let error_as_text = std::str::from_utf8(&error).unwrap();
    let mut error_message = result.unwrap_err();
    error_message.reverse();
    assert_eq!(output_as_text, "good line\n");
    assert_eq!(error_message.join("\n"), "fatal error at 3\nfatal error");
    assert_eq!(error_as_text, "Error: error at 1\ncaused by: bad line\n");
}
```

And what I *want* would be tested by changing the last two assertions to this:

```
    assert_eq!(error_message.join("\n"), "fatal error at 3\nline: 'third'\nfatal error");
    assert_eq!(error_as_text, "Error: error at 1\nline: 'first'\ncaused by: bad line\n");
```

Mind you, because errors are possible when *decoding* the line (bad unicode), not all errors would have the line, though all of them have the *number* of the line.

I've tried to print the line when printing out the errors on `main_loop`, and I've tried to extract and re-use the result in `process`. I could change `and_then(eval)` to `and_then(|line| { let r = eval(line); match r /* etc */ })`, but that would be as cumbersome as when I add the line number -- that cumbersomeness reflects an issue with error-chain, the crate being used for error handling.

Is there a pattern Ruster old-hands know about that would make this simpler?

Comment: I think it would be much more useful, if you could reduce the amount of code and make it a compilable example.  TBF I still don't understand what you try to achieve here.  What is the end goal?  Different levels of error types in `Result::Err`?  How would you want to use the returned error?

Answer (score 2):

Just print the line inside the `and_then`:

```
let result = next_line
    .and_then(|line| {
        re_encode_json(&line, bin_queries, text_queries)
            .map_err(|e| {
                println!("Error while processing {}", line);
                e
            })
    });
```

Or if you want to store the line for later:

```
let result = next_line
    .and_then(|line| {
        re_encode_json(&line, bin_queries, text_queries)
            .map_err(|e| { Error::with_chain (e, line) })
    });
```

Comment: Instead of `Err(e)`, it should have been `e`, but it's a good answer I had not thought of. Unfortunately, that prints the line at the wrong moment, and it's not testable. I could create a new error to store it and chain it, but then I fall in the same issue I already had with the line number chaining.